# How to add realtime time-stamp in postman?

Tags: api, postman

I want to add time-stamp while requesting API using Postman. But when I add it, I am getting response fail.

I am adding like:

```
Time-Stamp:1570703286
```

Comment: Where you want to add timestamp? in a request uri? body? header?

Comment: I want it in Header

Answer (score 0):

When I did research alot for the solution I got to know that we have write Pre-request script for that.

```
const dateNow= new Date();
pm.environment.set('currentDate', dateNow / 1000);
```

Here I am attaching screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: Depending on the type of timestamp format you want in that header - you could just use `{{$timestamp}}` as the header value to get the value from the original question.